# Finding a string in C#

Tags: c#

As I am new to C# I don't know How to find a string in it
Following is a sample data.

```
NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA s/o SHAMA NAZ.
MUHAMMAD USAMAN S/OABDUREHMAN s/o WEL MARK (PVT) LTD.
MAHA SECURITIES (PVT) LTD s/o REHAN AHMED.
AL-REHMAT TRADERS PVT LTD s/o Yasar Ayub S/O Mohammad Ayub Khan.
MUHAMMAD HASSAN s/o BATA SHOES SADDAR BAZAR C/O RANA KHALID PERVAIZ.
```

I want first name to be saved in `FIRST NAME ARRAY` and last name in second array. How can I do that?

I want my data to be represented as follows:

```
 | First Name------------------ | Last Name |
1| NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA -- | SHAMA NAZ |
2| MUHAMMAD USAMAN --- | ABDUREHMAN |
3| MAHA SECURITIES ----- - | REHAN AHMED |
4| AL-REHMAT --------------- | Yasar Ayub |
5| MUHAMMAD HASSAN ---- | RANA KHALID PERVAIZ |
```

Is there any solution with which i can solve all these expression in C#?

Comment: I'm sure you have made some attempts so far, right? Could you edit your post and clarify where you are stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your sample data contains new line characters?

```
string data = "NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA s/o SHAMA NAZ.\n MUHAMMAD USAMAN S/OABDUREHMAN s/o WEL MARK (PVT) LTD.\n MAHA SECURITIES (PVT) LTD s/o REHAN AHMED.\n AL-REHMAT TRADERS PVT LTD s/o Yasar Ayub S/O Mohammad Ayub Khan.\n MUHAMMAD HASSAN s/o BATA SHOES SADDAR BAZAR C/O RANA KHALID PERVAIZ.";
```

If there are not new line character, split by dot character since it marks end of each entry. Otherwise (or if you don't know), split by both new line and dot character.

```
var split = data.Split(new []{'.', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now, for storing data you really want to use a class

```
class Person
{ 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Get the data - split every line by "s/o" and then take first and second item from the newly created split. The third item is optional, it is a company I guess.

```
var persons = split.Select(entry => entry.Split(new[] { "s/o" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                   .Select(lineSplit => new Person { FirstName = lineSplit[0], LastName = lineSplit[1] })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: how can i write a regular expression for a string for abcdeg s/o abcdef ?

Comment: That's another question. I'll give you an advise. Just don't. Regular expressions are very powerfull but very often used without justification. They can get very slow. For a simple task like you have, use string operations intead.

Comment: i am reading all these strings from a file in order to split them i need to know what type of a string is for e.g asdsd s/o sadasd  or 1 s/o 2 s/0 3 ..

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) function, split them by "s/o", like this:

```
string data = "NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA s/o SHAMA NAZ. MUHAMMAD USAMAN S/OABDUREHMAN s/o WEL MARK (PVT) LTD.  MAHA SECURITIES (PVT) LTD s/o REHAN AHMED. AL-REHMAT TRADERS PVT LTD s/o Yasar Ayub S/O Mohammad Ayub Khan. MUHAMMAD HASSAN s/o BATA SHOES SADDAR BAZAR C/O RANA KHALID PERVAIZ."

string[] splittedData = data.Split(new string[]{"s/o"}, stringSplitOptions.None);
```

The "SplittedData" is an array of your data which contains the "FirstName" and "LastName.

furthur split them using space like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < splittedData.Length; i++)
{
string[] firstNameLastName = splittedData[i].Split(' ');
// the index 0 of firstNameLastName array is the first name, add this to the first name array, and the index 1 of firstNameLastName array is the last name, add this to the last name array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  dont konw where are these datas, and I assume they are in a file of several lines
each line is one person

```
    StreamReader reader=new StreamReader("file.txt");
    int index=1;
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line=reader.ReadLine();
        string []nameparams=line.Split(new string[]{"s/o"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}------|{2}|",index,nameparams[0],nameparams[1]);
    }
    reader.Close();
```